# NSFetchedResultsController returns row and populates table, but the table cell labels disappear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am having an issue with the NSFetchedResultsViewController. Here is my setup. My apps rootViewController is a TabBarController. Connected to my UITabBarController are two view controllers (so i have 2 tabs). The UIViewControllers associated with each tab have containers where i embed another UIViewController. One of these UIViewControllers has a UITableView that i am attempting to populate with data coming from CoreData. So, to populate the UITableView, i am using NSFetchedResultsViewController.

Here is my strange problem. If I make the UIViewController with the UITableView / NSFetchedResultsController the first tab, so that it is shown first when the app loads, everything works great and I see my 3 rows of data in the tableview as expected (i am setting two labels in each custom table cell).

[Labels visible for each row when on first tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLdA0.png)

However, if i make that ViewController be the second tab, launch the app, view my first tab, and then tap the second tab where my tableview resides, 3 rows are created, but i do not see the labels, just a blank row with a disclosure indicator.

[Labels disappear, but the rows are still created when on second tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSpLZ.png)

The NSFectchedResultsController seems to be working properly because even in the case where the cells labels are missing, but the rows are created, I log out the value that should be shown, and the value prints, so i my managedobject has the values.

Previously i was not using CoreData, and was just populating the table with simple objects in memory, and everything was working correctly when tapping between tabs…the data always appeared. I only began to see this problem after implementing the fetchedResultsController.

Here is my code:

```
class OrderListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var delegate: OrderListViewControllerDelegate?

    private lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ListOrder")
        let dateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "statusSubmittedAt", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [dateSort]

        let pred = NSPredicate(format: "(statusBuilt == %@ and statusCancelled == %@ and statusComplete == %@ and statusSubmitted == %@)", NSNumber(bool: false), NSNumber(bool: false), NSNumber(bool: false), NSNumber(bool: true))
        request.predicate = pred

        let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)!.managedObjectContext
        let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        controller.delegate = self

        return controller
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        //Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController.sections!.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections! as [NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo]
        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OrderListTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? OrderListTableViewCell)!

        // Configure the cell...
        let order = (fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? ListOrder)!

        // Update Cell
        if let userDisplayName = order.userDisplayName {
            print(userDisplayName) //prints correct value to console
            cell.orderName.text = userDisplayName
        }

        if let placementDescription = order.tagPlacementDescription {
            cell.orderName.text = cell.orderName.text! + " - \(placementDescription)"
            print(placementDescription) //prints correct value to console

        }

        if let orderTime = order.statusSubmittedAt {
            cell.orderTime.text = String.stringTimeFromDate(orderTime)
        }

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        self.delegate?.didSelectOrder(self, order:(fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? ListOrder)!)
    }
}
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. I am out of ideas.

Comment: How do you embed the controller with the table view in the container view?  Could the labels be present but zero size or outside the screen bounds?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, this usually happens when I add a new item to my core data from a pushed view controller and I navigate back. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You code seems to be correct, but I rather offer you make your NSFetchResultsController how it's usually implemented in code. You need to implement at least three methods in your delegate

1. `controllerWillChangeContent:`
2. `controllerDidChangeContent:`
3. `controller:DidChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath`

Hope this helps.

P. S. Are you sure that your values printed every time as method for cell is called. Try to set breakpoint or else-clause go check this. Additionally, I would re-check identifiers for cell and connection of outlets

Comment: I actually do have those methods implemented as well, but had commented them out to see if they were the culprit (and removed them from the code i posted). If i read in the data with the NSFetchResultsController and the data doesn't change, those delegate methods would not be called from my understanding. I get the same problem if they are implemented or not. Yes, my values are printed out every time when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called. I believe my identifiers and outlets are correct as well, since the table cells appear properly when my view controller is on the first tab.

Comment: Well, could you upload you projects anywhere so I could download it and check it later for mistakes? I found this bug quite interesting